# Convergent or Divergent Sequence?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

> Is
>   $$\frac{3n + (-1)^n}{n^6 + 5n}$$
>   Convergent or Divergent? Explain.

For the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ I got the following:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{3n + (-1)^n}{n^6 + 5n}\Rightarrow\frac{\infty\pm \infty}{\infty + \infty}$$

Would the limit be $0$ (convergent) since the denominator is approaching $\infty$ faster than the numerator?

Or is there another solution?

Comment: That limit is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. You have, as $n$ tends to $+\infty$,
$$
\frac{3n + (-1)^n}{n^6 + 5n} =\frac{3}{n^5}\frac{1 + \frac{(-1)^n}{3n}}{1 +\frac{5}{n^4}} \sim \frac{3}{n^5}
$$
thus: convergence.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on this solution?

Comment: nevermind. I am guessing that you divided $\frac{3n}{n^6}$ by $n$?

Comment: @Jessica Please, see the edit. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you take out $\frac{3n}{n^6}$? How would you know to, I mean.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that $0<\frac{3n+(-1)^n}{n^6+5n}<\frac{4n}{n^6}=\frac{4}{n^5}$ for $n\geq 1$, and think of the squeeze theorem.

In other words, yes, the limit is $0$, but your reasoning should be improved.

Comment: how did you get $\frac{4n}{n^6}$?

Comment: We increase the numerator and decrease the numerator: $3n+(-1)^n\leq 3n+1\leq 4n$; $n^6+5n>n^6$. Hence we have $\frac{3n+(-1)^n}{n^6+5n}<\frac{4n}{n^6}$.

Comment: So did you just use $4n$ because it is simpler than $3n+1$? even though the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for both is still $\infty$?

Comment: Yes - the other would work as well, but I found it to be simpler.